# axios post data format

Tags: jquery, ajax, axios

I want axios to post data like the following format(use jquery ajax.post)

[image]

```
var data = {};
data.params = querystring.stringify({'cmd': 'getUnreadCount', 'isNewAdmin':''});
data = querystring.stringify(data);
axios.post(url, data);
```

But actually it was posted like this. How to change params to object like above.

### [image]

Comment: Try to wrap it by double-quotes like `querystring.stringify("{'cmd': 'getUnreadCount', 'isNewAdmin':''}");`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you need to use `JSON.stringify` instead of `querystring.stringify` in the second line to serialize `params`.

```
var data = querystring.stringify({
  params: JSON.stringify({'cmd': 'getUnreadCount', 'isNewAdmin':''})
});
axios.post(url, data);
```